# Does PEX tubing need to be secured to attic joists?

Tags: plumbing, pex

I am slowly replacing my pin-holed leaking galvanized plumbing, piece be piece with PEX and Sharkbite connectors.  The old galvanized is secured, in many places by both clamps and u-nails.  What is the best practice with PEX?

Comment: When you say piece by piece, how short of pex are you talking about.  One of the best features of pex is that you can make long runs with it without many fittings.  This benefit also helps to make up for the smaller inner wall of PEX vs copper.

Comment: I have replaced 3 small sections of 4 - 6 feet with straight PEX pipe, and just recently bypassed a 15 foot section between floors (unreachable without several ceiling cuts) with a 30 foot run through two joined attics attaching back up to the old pipes in the master bath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  There are special plastic clamps that can be used with PEX so that the pipe does not wear.  You should secure it about every 32 to 48 inches, and anywhere to prevent the expansion/contraction of the pipe to cause wear.  It is not necessary to clamp where the pipe runs through holes in wooden joists/studs.

[image]